# What type of authentication in generated in laravel with the make:auth command

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I just wanted to ask a simple question about laravel:
What type of authentication is generated when you create authentication with `php artisan make:auth`.

I mean what is generated in background:

1. OAuth
2. Basic Authentication
3. Token Authentication
4. JWT
5. Open ID

And what is used to tell that you're authentication when you go from one page to another, or in general what does middleware auth() use to make that kind of authorization.

Thank you for your responses!
Wish you all good health

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel uses session based authentication when you use `php artisan make:auth`. You can also use Basic Authentication or Token Authentication (with some modification) out of the box. The `Authenticate` middleware checks if the user is still logged in with the correct session that is send in each request via the browser.

There are also loads of packages available that will allow you to use OAuth.

You can read more about authentication here: https://laravel.com/docs/authentication#http-basic-authentication